# How to resolve an aborted request on awaited call to HttpStatusCode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, http-status-codes, aerogear

I'm awaiting a call to send a push notification using the [Aero Gear .Net client](https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-unifiedpush-dotnet-client). The return value from the call to push is a `System.Net.HttpStatusCode`. The expected code if the push is successful is "Accepted".

But when I await the call to the SendPushNotification method, it throws a `"The request was aborted. The connection was closed unexpectedly"`error before the HttpStatusCode is returned from the method at this line:

```
System.Net.HttpStatusCode status = await client.Send(unifiedMessage);
```

I marked the call from the controller up to the push method as async, and added await where there was a call to an async method.

**Question:**

How can you resolve an aborted request on awaited call to HttpStatusCode?

This is a gist of the call trickled down from the initial call in the controller to the push class method:

**Controller:**

```
//In Controller Post action that calls SendPushNotification

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Order exec_order)
{
    try
    {


        //Send a push notification with the order details
        try
        {
            MyLogger.FileLogger.Info("Before Push Notification");
            System.Net.HttpStatusCode status = await PushsClassLibrary.PushNotification.SendPushNotification(exec_order.Application", "Order Summary");
            MyLogger.FileLogger.Info("Push Notification Status: " + status);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //request aborted error caught here
        {
            MyLogger.FileLogger.Error("Push Notification Exception -" + ex.Message);
        }


}
```

**Push Class:**

```
//In PushNotification class containing SendPushNotification
public static async Task<System.Net.HttpStatusCode> SendPushNotification(string messageToPush, string serviceName )
{
    string[] listUsers = users.ToArray();
    unifiedMessage.criteria.alias = listUsers;

    System.Net.HttpStatusCode status = await client.Send(unifiedMessage);    
    return status;
}
```

Comment: are you certain that your method `SendPushNotification()` not throwing any exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that status code you will want to check is `HttpStatusCode.OK` and I'm pretty sure that the error you get: "The request was aborted. The connection was closed unexpectedly" is an exception. Are you sure that the AeroGear server is running and that you don't need Proxy configuration for your `PushsClassLibrary`?

Otherwise the AeroGear Project also has a [C# sender library](https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-unifiedpush-dotnet-client) that you could use.

Comment: That is the library I'm using already. The proxy config is there I've hidden it and shown a gist of the code.